# Generate random xml / web service response based on xsd / wsdl

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I've just seen a case of the same old familiar story - we are trying to integrate to an external 3rd party web service, but the development has been done using a simulated web service.  Of course as soon as we integrate with the actual web service we find that our code makes assumptions about the web service response, and so everything falls apart!

Does there exist a tool that can generate random valid xml fragments / soap responses given a xsd schema / wsdl?

Comment: I don't know if such a tool exists but if so I would also be pleased to hear about it

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [Elvior](http://www.elvior.com/xml-simulator/features).  It's a general XML testing suite and I think it might be able to do what you're looking for.